# Chromedriver - save Chrome cache and preload it into another chrome instances

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have selenium e2e tests on java for angular app. 
Running 30 threads of headless chrome in incognito mode.
Loading start page sometimes takes up to 10 seconds as browser downloads a lot of `.js, .png, etc` files from server. 
Start page is the same for all tests.
Want to reduce e2e execution time. One of ideas was to get start page before all tests, than save cached content and than start all test instances of chrome with that preloaded cache.
Is it possible? If yes - how to do that?

Currently looking on this [switches](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/precache/core/precache_switches.cc?sq=package:chromium&type=cs) but i'm not to strong in that

Comment: The path of the profile is accessible via  `browser.driver.getSession().getCapability('chrome').userDataDir`. You can then  start a new instance with the `user-data-dir` argument.

Comment: yeah, looks it's possible, but only in non-incognito mode as in incognito all cache is stored in RAM.